# Failing to post json to an endpoint using curl

Tags: php, curl

Im trying to create a simple api that will post json to an endpoint using curl and php. its giving me an error whereby its saying unsupported media type and i need help seeing what it is i might be doing wrong, here is the code

```
<?php

$data = array("saleAmount"=>"2000","cashBack"=>"800","posUser"=>"John","tenderType"=>"SWIPE","currency"=>"RTGS","transactionId"=>'0001');
$payload = json_encode($data);
echo $payload;
// prepare curl
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost:9111/api/requests');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                
    'Content-Type: application/jsonp',                                                     
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($payload))                                                                       
);
// Submit the POST request
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo json_encode($result);
// Close cURL session handle
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: Should your content type not be application/json instead?

Comment: yes thanks for that fixed it to json but its still giving me the same result

Comment: Please share the full and exact error message, along with your attempts to resolve the problem. Also, it could be easier to use a library like Guzzle for this, such that you don't have to fiddle around with the specific cURL settings

Comment: The error that im getting is a status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type" and its displaying the path name that it is failing to post to

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also share your attempts to resolve the problem, as nobody knows anything about the API you are using

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your API is expecting a different media type than the one you are providing in your quest.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415

Make sure that your API supports the content-type `application/json`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $url="";//path of api
    $ch=curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json')
            );
    $data = array("saleAmount"=>"2000","cashBack"=>"800","posUser"=>"John","tenderType"=>"SWIPE","currency"=>"RTGS","transactionId"=>'0001');
    $data=json_encode($data);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
    $response=curl_exec($ch); 
    print_r($response);die;
    curl_close($ch);
Append your url in $url and check this once.
```